# NHibernate: Cannot assign property value in entity's constructor

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When I run the following code, at B's constructor, I got a NullReferenceException. I cannot assign value to B's Number property.

Models:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        this.Number = 1;
        if (this.Number != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to assign value in A's constructor");
        }
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        this.Number = 1;
        // Throws NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        if (this.Number != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to assign value in B's constructor");
        }
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class AMappings : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMappings()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Number);
        References(x => x.B).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class BMappings : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMappings()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Number);
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create connection string
        string connectionString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                                      {
                                          DataSource = @".\r2",
                                          InitialCatalog = "TestNHibernateMappings",
                                          IntegratedSecurity = true
                                      }.ConnectionString;

        // Create SessionFactory
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                      .MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)
                      .ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
            .Add(typeof(AMappings))
            .Add(typeof(BMappings)))
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildConfiguration()
        .BuildSessionFactory();

        // Create test object in DB
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var a = new A();
                a.B = new B();
                session.Save(a);
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }

        // Read test object from DB
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var a = session.Get<A>(1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void BuildSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);
    }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0.4000, FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that `Number` is virtual.

`A.B` is being lazy-loaded.  NHibernate creates a proxy for `B` which overrides each virtual property in the class.  The first time one of the non-`Id` properties is accessed, NHibernate will load the data from the database to populate the object.

Since this proxy class is a subclass of `B`, `B`'s constructor will be called before the proxy constructor.  When `B`'s constructor sets the virtual property `Number`, it is calling the `Number` property as defined in the proxy subclass, which has not yet been initialized.

For a more thorough discussion of constructors and inheritance, see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html

To fix this, convert any properties you wish to set in the constructor to use backing fields instead of auto-properties, then set the field instead of the property in the constructor.

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        _number = 1;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    private int _number;

    public virtual int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set { _number = value; }
    }
}
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it effectively avoids touching virtual methods or properties in the constructor.